# Detect disabled or unpowered Devices using WIA

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, wia

I am using the WIA library for a  vb.net application to get the list of scanner devices. I need only the available devices so I can connect to then and see if they have ADF capabilities or other properties.

```
For Each info As DeviceInfo In manager.DeviceInfos
    If (info.Type = WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType) Then
        Dim dv as Device = info.Connect()
    End If
Next
```

If the device is not powered the Connect() method hangs for 20 seconds.

I've tried calling the method on a separate thread using BackgroundWorker Class. My idea was to call the Connect method  on all the scanners, wait 1 seconds and only use the MyScanDvClass that have the Connected property set to true. The problem is that it blocks the UI until all the background workers complete execution.

```
 Public Class MyScanDvClass
     Public Property dv As Device
     Public Property Connected As Boolean = False
 End Class

 Private lst_scc = New List(Of MyScanDvClass)
 Public Sub InitiateScanners()
     Dim manager As New DeviceManagerClass
     For Each info As DeviceInfo In manager.DeviceInfos
         If (info.Type = WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType) Then
             Dim bw As New BackgroundWorker
             Dim sdc As New MyScanDvClass
             AddHandler bw.DoWork, Sub(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
                                       Dim local_sdc As MyScanDvClass = e.Argument
                                       Try
                                           local_sdc.dv = info.Connect()
                                       Catch ex As Exception
                                       End Try
                                       local_sdc.Connected = True
                                       e.Result = local_sdc
                                   End Sub

             bw.RunWorkerAsync(sdc)
         End If
     Next
 End Sub
```

My project is on .NET 3.5 so I don't have a lot of alternative librarys.